# Were these review audits justified?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I failed 3 First Questions audits recently. The first one was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34406058). At the time of the review the question looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76049290/1). I chose to *'Share Feedback'* to ask for more details because the question was just an error message and a documentation link with no code. I am not an AWS expert, but usually error messages are accompanied by a piece of code or a configuration file. Rarely are error messages alone enough to answer a question. I have since edited the question to be better formatted; this is what I should have done instead.

The next one was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34416409). I chose *'Looks OK'* because at least at first the question appeared fleshed out and well researched. Yes, the question is opinion based, but as a reviewer with no context this was not clear. A [Stack Overflow moderator even agreed with me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34416409) that the audit was *'Suboptimal'* and removed the resulting review suspension.

The third one was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34430772). I chose *'Looks OK'* because the question did include a paragraph of elaboration and included some code. However on second review the question fails to specify exactly where they are struggling and needs more details or clarity. I should have shared feedback and asked for more details such as debugging details, and be more careful to ensure that debugging questions with code and a 'decent looking' amount of details actually have adequate debugging details to answer.

Review audits/suspensions are ostensibly to prevent robo-reviewers and make sure we are actually reviewing the tasks; I was. I just thought in good faith, at first, that the first question may have needed more details and the latter 2 were maybe not 'great' questions but 'looked okay,' at least to someone like me with little/no subject matter expertise or context. I am requesting the review suspension to be revoked/shortened (It has already been established that the second audit was poor, so even if the other audits were good, I should have a 4 day suspension and not 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion:

The first question was badly formatted but okay. I don't see why going to ask for details should cause you to fail an audit. Maybe the audit system needs to be tweaked a little. Sometimes an error message is all that's needed to point to a widespread but incomprehensible problem which someone can explain how to solve.

The second question is...... barely okay, I guess? On a surface level it appears to be looking for an off-site resource, but it's actually more like looking for the source of a quote or the meaning of a word. I'm not sure that it really qualifies for closure as opinion-based. I've noticed that many users have a habit of closing too many things as opinion-based and if this question were not already deleted I'd vote to reopen it. Opinion-based does not mean "there is more than one possible way to write a correct answer". Regardless, it's still low quality - rambling, unfocused.

The third question is a standard issue "here's my code dump, what's the problem?" which of course should be closed as needing more debugging info or problem details. You simply failed that one by not actually reading it.

P.S. if you are unsure how to handle a review, the correct answer is always "skip"